# What is wrong with "more number of"?

Tags: grammaticality, comparative-constructions

I am writing a technical article and one of the reviewers had a comment for the following statement:

> When compared to a generic setup, our technique can potentially store **more number of blocks** per set due to compression.

The reviewer pointed out that the grammar of this usage "more number of blocks" needs a second look.

What is wrong with the same? How do I correct it?

Comment: You can write "*more blocks per set*" or "*a higher number of blocks per set*". Or "*increase the number of blocks per set*". "*More number*" makes no sense.

Comment: I am going with "more blocks per set". Turns out that I have used this phrase at many places: "As more number of applications". Corrected them too. If you can post your comment as answer, would like to mark it as solved. Thanks.

Comment: you could use 'a larger number of blocks' - it's because Number is an object

Comment: How do I use it in this sentence: "As more applications run on our system effective utilization of the resources is the key for improving system performance". I want to convey that the number of applications that run on our system will increase with time.

Comment: By **it** do you mean **more**? In this case your example is fine. You can say **more Xs** where X can be a measurable thing. **more applications** or **more blocks** or **more power**.

Answer (score 3):

*More*, used before countable nouns, already means *a greater number of*.

> our technique can potentially store a greater number of number of blocks (bad)
>
> our technique can potentially store a greater number of blocks (good)
>
> our technique can potentially store more blocks (good)

So adding *number of* is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Just "more blocks".  More blocks implies the number of blocks has increased.  When you say "more number" you change your focus from the blocks to the numbers.

> There were more blocks.
>
> Both the size and the number of blocks increased.
>
> The blocks were bigger and there were more of them.